Annihilator attack target is switched
If a player redirects the attack of a creature with Annihilator (such as Ulamog's Crusher) to another player using Portal Manipulator or Windshaper Planetar does the original person being attacked sacrifice for annihilator or does the new attacked player sacrifice for annihilator?

When Annihilator resolves, the player that is (or was) actually being attacked by that creature has to sacrifice.
During multiplayer games, depending on the variant being played, one or all of the opposing players become the defending player.

802.1. Some multiplayer games allow the active player to attack multiple other players. If this option is used, a player can also choose to attack only one player during a particular combat.


802.2. As the combat phase starts, the attacking player doesn’t choose an opponent to become the defending player. Instead, all the attacking player’s opponents are defending players during the combat phase.

However, Annihilator and other effects that refer to a defending player only affect one player, the one that's actually being attacked by a creature.

802.2a Any rule, object, or effect that refers to a “defending player” refers to one specific defending player, not to all of the defending players. If an ability of an attacking creature refers to a defending player, or a spell or ability refers to both an attacking creature and a defending player, then unless otherwise specified, the defending player it’s referring to is the player that creature is attacking, the controller of the planeswalker that creature is attacking, or the protector of the battle that player is attacking. If that creature is no longer attacking, the defending player it’s referring to is the player that creature was attacking before it was removed from combat, the controller of the planeswalker that creature was attacking before it was removed from combat, or the protector of the battle that player was attacking before it was removed from combat. If a spell or ability could apply to multiple attacking creatures, the appropriate defending player is individually determined for each of those attacking creatures. If there are multiple defending players that could be chosen, the controller of the spell or ability chooses one.


In this example Ulamog hasn't left combat and is still attacking, so don't understand why you bolded the no longer attacking clause.

Because I also answered the case when the Crusher has left combat.

So just to clarify, if Ulamog attacks player A, during the declare attackers step player A redirects the attack to player B player A would still need to sacrifice for the annihilator effect.

@NakotoAmagi No. Ulamog attacks player A, Annihilator goes on the stack, someone redirects Ulamog to player B, Annihilator resolves, B has to sacrifice.

More generally, if you redirect the attack while the Annihilator trigger is on the stack, player B is the defending player as the trigger resolves, and they're the one who needs to sacrifice. If the annihilator trigger resolves first, then player A is the defending player at that time, and they sacrifice. Redirecting the attack after that doesn't go back in time and change what happened while resolving the annihilator trigger.
